# Coding for each in VB in the markup

Tags: c#, vb.net

I know I can place this code in the markup to create a repeater for a C# markup but can I do something similar in VB.net

```
<% foreach (var c in Contacts) { %>
<div class="footer">
    <% if (c.Custody != null) { %>
        <label>Custody:</label> <%= c.Custody.Name %><br />
    <% } %>
</div>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% For Each itm In tContacts %>
 <div class="footer">
    <% If itm.Custody IsNot Nothing Then %>
        <label>Custody:</label> <%= itm.Custody.Name %><br/>
    <% End If %>
 </div>
<% Next %>
```

This should do the trick! Happy coding!

Comment: Mark this as the correct answer if you are satisfied with it.